# Using node appium-xcuitest-driver to test ios app

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, appium, functional-testing

```
const { XCUITestDriver } = require('appium-xcuitest-driver');

const automationConfig = {
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '11.2',
    deviceName: 'iPhone 7',
    app: __dirname + '/cameo.app',
    bundleId: 'com.app.myapp',
};

const driver = new XCUITestDriver();

driver.createSession(automationConfig)
    .then(() => {
        //WHAT DO I DO NOW??
    })
```

The above code opens an iOS simulator, downloads my app, and opens it. How do I find an element and click on it?

If I do `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//whatever-xpath"))` it tells me that `By` is not defined. But `By` is not included in `driver`. I looked through the appium docs, but the API guide is still a TODO in there >: |

Do I need to import another module to help with this?

I haven't been able to find any useful code samples after extensive Googling, either.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `appium-xcuitest-driver` for e2e testing, it is better and easier to use [wd.js](https://github.com/admc/wd) wrapper around it:

```
const wd = require('wd')

desired = {
  platformName: 'iOS',
  platformVersion: '11.1',
  deviceName: 'iPhone SE',
  automationName: 'XCUITest',
  app: <path to app>
}
const server = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 4723
}
const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote(server)
await driver.init(desired)
const el1 = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId(<Valid Accessibility Identifier>)
const el2 = await driver.elementsByXPath(<Valid Xpath>)
```

Another point: it is used for functional tests in [appium-xcuitest-driver repo](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/test/functional/basic/find-e2e-specs.js)

It is important to start appium service before running tests:

- install appium: `npm install -g appium`
- Start service with simple command `appium`

Comment: Thank you for your response! How do I know what server I should be pointing towards? Using `appium-xcuitest-driver` I wasn't specifying one. My response is ```{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4723
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 4723 }```

Comment: You need to install appium: `npm install -g appium`
And then start server with simple command `appium`

Comment: I love you. I mean that in the least weird way possible.